# Hibernate - Use formula on column from Secondary table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, formula, secondary-table

I have the following entity :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "myTable")
@SecondaryTable(name = "myOtherTable", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "someId"))
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ContactEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;
  @Column(name = "firstName", table = "myOtherTable")
  private String firstName;
  @Column(name = "lastName", table = "myOtherTable")
  private String lastName;

}
```

firstName and lastName from myOtherTable should be trimed.
I tried using `@Formula("trim(firstName)"` but I get the following error `firstName does not exist in table myTable`
Is there a way to apply a formula to a secondary table ? (without using select ... from myOtherTable)?
Or should I use a converter like below
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Formula` makes the field read-only so you probably want to use the converter instead.
From the javadoc:

> Defines a formula (derived value) which is a SQL fragment that acts as
> a @Column alternative in most cases. Represents read-only state.